# How to Get Count of the Particular records in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, subquery

I am taking various status from a employee table which has 230 records with below 5 status.
I have written query for taking the count for each and every status but now need combined count of Status A and B as AB.

My Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Status AS Status,
           COUNT(Status ) AS StatusCount
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    GROUP BY Status
```

My Query Output is:

```
Status    Count
A           100
B           50
C           30
D           10
E           40
```

I want result as A&B Combined and remaining as same.

```
Status      Count
A&B          150
C             30
D             10
E             40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case`

```
SELECT case when Status in ('A','B') 
            then 'A&B'
            else Status
       end AS Status,
       COUNT(Status) AS StatusCount
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY case when Status in ('A','B') 
              then 'A&B'
              else Status
         end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `decode` also

```
SELECT decode(status,'A','A&B','B','A&B',status) AS Status,
       COUNT(status) AS StatusCount
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY decode(status,'A','A&B','B','A&B',status) AS Status
```